# Using Asana API to Copy a Project

Tags: asana

Is there a way to copy an Asana project using the [API](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/), similar to the "Use as a Template (Copy Project)" functionality available in the web interface?

We use 'template' projects heavily and now we are looking to automate this process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As @vbjain said, this isn't currently possible without fetching all tasks (one request - unless there are subtasks to copy) and then re-posting them (N requests). However, I've added this to our list of requested features. It's an interesting one. I suppose you could do something like: `POST /projects { template: { id: XXX, fields: ["name", "followers", "assignee"] }, name: "My copy" }`

Comment: Thanks, we will do as @vbjain suggests and copy each task manually. I'll look out for the copy api though - Templates are awesome!

Comment: +1 on the feature request. Wanted this supported in Zapier (it's not) so will likely have to roll my own. Copy project would be great out-of-the-box though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till now Asana API does not facilitate this. But still if you want to make it work, fetch your template project using Asana API and fetch the tasks too. After that create new project and paste your tasks or any other details that you want. That will make things work for you.

Comment: It's not as easy as you say. Though, Asana is extremely popular now, it's API is unbelievably poor and inconvenient to use. Regarding the case of copying project, it's still impossible to copy dependencies.  
It means that if you have a task that is dependent on another task, you won't be able to save this dependency (until you do it manually). Awful!